# ubiquityIdentityToken Consistent on Device

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I want to make sure I understand the `ubiquityIdentityToken` correctly.

The ubiquityIdentityToken obtained on each device for each iCloud account will be consistent and unique on that device, but may be inconsistent across devices.

Is this true?

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFileManager/ubiquityIdentityToken) for the Apple Docs on the `ubiquityIdentityToken`.

Answer (score 3):

I did some very basic tests between simulator and device and I found that `ubiquityIdentityToken` is unique per device/iCloud account.

I logged in into iCloud with different iCloud accounts and each time the returned token would match the one that was previously returned for the same combination of device/iCloud account.

Comment: It can't be consistent for both device and iCloud. Isen't it just consistent for the same iCloud?

Comment: If it is determined by iCloud, a user should be to switch between their devices, and the id should be the same - because they are logged with the same account

Comment: Nevermind. I think I understand now. A new id is created when a icloud user opens the app for the first time.                                                                               When opened again by the same user, it will have the same id as before. (But only on the same device).                                I did not get a consistent id with same iCloud on two devices

Comment: ..So it confirms the above